# What are some other idiomatic ways of saying getting into trouble?

Tags: phrase-request

Request: what are some other idiomatic way of saying getting into trouble? Or some alternatives (slangs, idioms, phrases)?

In context like:

> I've gotten into trouble, so I can't contact you right now.

Ideally, is there any websites or dictionary where I can search for phrases, idioms, etc. by typing the meaning I want to convey?

Comment: What is the criteria you use to judge "most idiomatic"? Because that varies widely with the speaker and intended receiver. "got into trouble" is fairly direct and informal but perfectly idiomantic between friends.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few colourful idioms which mean the same; some are more dated than others. Note that they are a bit UK centric.

"I'm in a pickle", or "I'm in a bit of a pickle".

"I'm in deep sh*t right now", which is fairly typical street slang, common in the UK.

"I'm up to my neck" (which could also just mean "I'm extremely busy").

... and can't think of any more off the top of my head, maybe I'll come back to this.